# fragment replace and back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that have one fragment , when I click in a button I do this

```
              Fragment newFragment = new OpinionesFragment();
              FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

              // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
              // and add the transaction to the back stack
              transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
              transaction.addToBackStack(null);

              // Commit the transaction
              transaction.commit();
```

A new Fragment appear in the screen. Later I press back button of the phone and when I click another one to the button the app gives me an error. What happens? What is the code to avoid this? Thank you, this is my log cat

```
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #116: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at com.triggertrap.sample.DetallesFragment.onCreateView(DetallesFragment.java:70)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #116: Duplicate id 0x7f080053, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.triggertrap.sample.OpinionesFragment
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-26 22:38:05.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4426):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Post the stack trace that the error triggers.

Comment: Dear, you need to share your logcat. So, that i can comment on it

Comment: Sounds like the fragment you want to inflate is not correctly written; remember, you always have to add a layout for each one if they are different

Comment: The fragment is correct because the first time the fragment opens correctly but when I press back and I try to open gives me error

Comment: can you please post `onCreateView` of your `OpinionesFragment`

Comment: Please, post the `onCreateView` of the `DetallesFragment`

Comment: Did you figured out what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the behaviour of the back button like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        // do nothing given that you might get the same error.
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // display previous fragment in the stack
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!